# Can "Avengers: Endgame" be used to answer MCU TV questions?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

After watching Season 5 of *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* I came here wondering

[Where has Deke gone?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/188043/358)

found the question justifiably closed as unknowable then.  But given the events of *Avengers: Endgame*, I think we know whether the *Back to the Future* invisible hand trope is at play in the MCU.  So can this question (and potential questions like it) be partially answered now?

Answer (score 5):

Sure. They're set in the same universe and the shows frequently have throwbacks to the movies, and even if I'm less aware of the other way around I guess that has happened as well.

I don't watch AOS so I don't know if the time travel is the same thing as *Endgame* though (quantum stuff and all), but if you're reasonably confident some documented answer can be patched up, go ahead. (well, you'll have to wait for it to be reopened - it may be, I sent it to queue with a reopen vote)

Comment: The films don't respect the events of the show. That's why they can have Coulson walking around in the open in the show but in the film he's still dead.

Comment: @Valorum is he? I thought he was like, hidden? In any case, I think the answer still holds, it's called a Universe for a reason :D

Comment: In the episode where they're cleaning up in Greenwich, he's not in the least bit hidden.